# How to iterate character by character in strings which lengths are larger than INT_MAX, or SIZE_MAX?

Tags: c, integer, max, size-t

C language, How to iterate character by character in strings which lengths are larger than INT_MAX, or SIZE_MAX?

How to find out that string length exceeded the any MAXIMUM SIZE applicable for the code below?

```
int len = strlen(item); 
int i=0; 
while (i <= len ) {
   //do smth
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Just use size_t. BTW, your loop runs too many times (extra 1 time).

Comment: Use size_t rather than int if your strings may be larger than MAX_INT.

Comment: Your `//do smth` should be where `strlen` is, because you would need your own `strlen` that checks for overflow.

Comment: `than MAX_INT` what is MAX_INT? Do you mean INT_MAX? `or MAX_SIZE?` What is "MAX_SIZE"? Do you mean SIZE_MAX? Please fix typos, if they are typos, in your question. If not, please specify then. `How to find out that string length exceeded the MAXIMUM SIZE?` What is "MAXIMUM SIZE"? Do you have an example implementation and compiler where a string can be larger than that MAX_SIZE?

Answer (score 2):

You can access characters in a string (or elements in an array generally) without integer indices by using pointers:

```
for (char *p = item; *p; ++p)
{
    // Do something.
    // *p is the current character.
}
```

Comment: thank you, i have added double check that i<SIZE_INT

Answer (score 0):

```
int len = strlen(item);
```

first, this is not an impedment to have a string longer thatn `INT_MAX`, but it will if you have to deal with it's length.  If you thinkg about the implementation of `strlen()` you'll see that, as how strings are defined (a sequence of chars in memory bounded by thre presence of a null char) you'll see that the only possible implementation is to search the string, incrementing the length as you traverse it searching for the first null char on it.  This makes your code very ineficient, because you first traverse the string searching for its end, then you traverse it a second time to do useful work.

```
int i=0; 
while (i <= len ) {
   //do smth
   i++;
}
```

it should be better to use directly a pointer, in a for loop, like this one:

```
char *p;
for (p = item; *p; p++) {
   // so something knowing that the char `*p` is the iterated char.
}
```

In this way, you navigate the string and stop when you find the null char, and you will not have to traverse it twice.

By the way, having strings longer than `INT_MAX` is quite difficult, because normally (and more with the new 64bit architectures) you are not allowed to create a so compact memory structure (this meaning that if you try to create a static array of that size, you will be fighting with the compiler, and if you try to `malloc()` such a huge amount of memory, you will end fighting wiht the operating system)

It's most normal that developers having to deal with huge amounts of memory, use an unseen structure to hold large amounts of characters.  Just imagine that you need to insert one char and this forces you to move one gigabyte of memory one position because you have no other way to make room for it.  It's simply unpractical to use such an amount.  A simple approach is to use a similar structure as it is used for the file data in a disk in a unix system.  The data has a series of direct pointers that point to fixed blocks of memory holding characters, but at some point those pointers become double pointers, pointing to an array of simple poointers, then a triple pointer, etc.  This way you can handle strings as sort as one byte (with just a memory page)to more than INT_MAX bytes, by selecting an appropiate size for the page and the number of pointers.

Another approach is the `mbuf_t` approach used by BSD software to handle networking packets.  This is expressely appropiate when you have to add to the string in front of it (e.g. to add a new protocol header) or to the rear of the packet (to add payload and/or checksum or trailing data)

One last thing... if you create an array of 5Gb, most probably every today operating system will swap it, as soon as you stop using part of it.  This will make your application to start swaping as soon as you move on the array, and probably you will not be able to run your application in a computer with a limited address space (like, today a 32bit machine is)